# How can I extract text from a flex container?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm attempting to extract some text from a website. The text however is between two tags and when I use getByXPath to extract the text I get everything except the text I need.

This is the layout of the website I'm scraping from: [Website HTML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RleOT.png)

The two highlighted portions are the pieces of text I actually need.

And this is the code I've got so far:

```
List<HtmlElement> name = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath("//ul/li/a[@class='title']");
List<HtmlElement> subText = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath("//ul/li/p[@data-af=' (Secret)']");
```

This however results in two lists:

name - which has HtmlAnchor objects within

```
[HtmlAnchor[<a class="title" data-af="10" href="/a180775/daddys-home-achievement">], HtmlAnchor[<a class="title" data-af="11" href="/a180776/protector-achievement">], HtmlAnchor[<a class="title" data-af="12" href="/a180777/sinclairs-solution-achievement">]]
```

subText - which has HtmlParagraph objects within.

```
[HtmlParagraph[<p data-af=" (Secret)">], HtmlParagraph[<p data-af=" (Secret)">], HtmlParagraph[<p data-af=" (Secret)">], HtmlParagraph[<p data-af=" (Secret)">]]
```

URL if you want to take a look at the whole website: https://truesteamachievements.com/game/BioShock-2-Remastered/achievements

I need the lists to look something like these:

```
["Daddy's Home", "Protector", "Sinclair's Solution"]
["Found your way back to the ruins of Rapture.", "Defended yourself against Lamb's assault in the train station.", "Joined forces with Sinclair in Ryan Amusements."]
```

This is the Html library I'm using : https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/apidocs/overview-summary.html

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is using Stream API:

```java
        List<HTMLElement> htmlElementList = new ArrayList<>();//get your list in needed way
        List<String> listOfTitles = htmlElementList.stream()
                .map(HTMLElement::getTitle)
                .toList();
```

More understanding, with `foreach` loop:

```java
        List<HTMLElement> htmlElementList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listOfTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (HTMLElement htmlElement:
             htmlElementList) {
            listOfTitles.add(htmlElement.getTitle());
        }
```

---

Not clear - which library you use for elements receiving. This is an example of the case if you use the `org.w3c.dom` library for `HtmlElement` definition. Otherwise - use the appropriate method for text receiving (except `getTitle()`), for example `getText()` - used for selenium `WebElement`, etc...